# Grep определенного процесса в Linux

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Находимся в Linux. Грепаю определенный процесс из top

```bash
top | grep soffbin
```

Что бы ограничить единоразово вывод в консоль результата, грепаю с ключами

```bash
top -b -n 1 | grep soffbin
```

Делаю еще лучше результат, вывожу через awk только 2 строчки ( отсеиваю лишнее )

```bash
top -b -n 1 | grep soffbin | awk '{print $9,$12}'
```

Результат будет примерно такой: 49.0 soffbin

Это покажет мне, что в данный момент соффбин грузит ЦПУ на 49%.

Вопрос: возможно ли сделать так:
Условие: софбин грузин цпу < 40% и что самое главное  более 10 минут. Тогда это поможет отсеять кратковременную нагрузку из за открытия допустим огромного файла и выявить некорректно поведение процесса в системе.

UPD, еще чуть улучшил вывод:

```bash
top -b -n 1 | grep soffbin | awk '{if ($9 > 40.0) print$1, $9,$12}'
```

Теперь будет условие, что нагрузка больше 40% и вывод с PID процесса:

> 9912 44.0 soffbin

Но опять же не понимаю, возможно ли задать последнее необходимое условие. Что бы данный процесс грузил более 40% хотя бы от 10 мин

Comment: `man perf` Специально же для таких задач. Не выдумывайте костылей.

Answer (score 0):

top может выводить данные в "кумулятивном" режиме. Для этого используется ключик -S.
Для Ваших целей можно анализировать, например, суммарное процессорное время, потраченное процессом между такими запусками top. Это даст понимание, какой процесс "слишком" активен в этот промежуток времени.
Но вообще согласен с предыдущим автором, выбор top в качестве инструмента такого анализа вызывает некоторые сомнения.